# Convert windows phone application to universal one

Tags: windows, windows-phone, visual-studio-2013, win-universal-app

Recently Microsoft announced ability to create universal applications in Visual Studio 2013. Is there any easy way to convert existing Windows Phone 8 application into universal or i have to create new project and properly move the code manually?

Comment: Have you tried the right-menu option to convert it to a universal project?

Comment: @PeterRitchie, checked once more - no such option. There was an option to convert 8 to 8.1 - did that, but no option to convert to universal application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not about converting a project type or moving code. You will have to port your app from one runtime to another. This is because the Universal project templates use the Windows Runtime APIs where as your existing Windows Phone 8 application uses the Silverlight APIs.

> Windows Phone Store apps use the same app model and UI framework as Windows Store apps do, and they use the Windows versions of common features such as background tasks. You will still be able to reuse a lot of your existing code, but these differences mean that it really is a porting exercise, more than just an update, to move a Windows Phone 8 to the new app model.
>   ([Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/dn655121%28v=vs.105%29.aspx))

There are some features that are available in Windows Phone 8 for which there is no Windows Phone Store (Universal apps) equivalent. See more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/dn642486%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Comment: You can run the apps on both platforms, but it's unlikely that the UX on one will be appropriate on the other--requiring manual tweaking of the UI.

Answer (score 2):

The right-menu option is "Add Windows 8.1...".  That will add Windows 8.1 support and add a Shared section to both projects so you can share code between then.

In your solution, right click your Windows Phone application and select "Add Windows 8.1..." and follow the prompts.

Comment: Did that.. Dont know why, but the compiled project just did not run on the actual device. Think will wait till normal Update 2 for VS2013, not RC...